# Insert type id in table

Tags: mysql, sql

How to insert score with value and score_id ? At server im know only score_type.name and score.value. How i can insert new score with score_type ? If score_type name exsist just get id and insert, else create, get id and insert.

[image: tables]

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO ...  SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to create the `score_type` if it doesn't exist:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO score_type (name) VALUES ("type_name");
```

Then use `INSERT ... SELECT` to insert the ID into the `score` table:

```
INSERT INTO score (value, score_type_id, player_id)
SELECT 123, id, "player_name"
FROM score_type
WHERE name = "type_name";
```

The first `INSERT` assumes you have a unique index on `score_type.name`. `IGNORE` means to fail silently if you try to insert a duplicate name.

Replace `123` and `player_name` with the known `score.value` and `score.player_id`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to fill the `score_type_id` dynamically by selecting it using the name:

```
INSERT INTO `score`(`value`, `score_type_id`, `player_id`) VALUES (1337, (SELECT id FROM score_type WHERE score_type.name = "test") ,"maio290");
```

The trick is just to use another query instead of a fixed value.

Comment: Why use a subquery instead of `INSERT ... SELECT`?

Comment: Not a specific reason, in SQL things usually can be done in a thousand ways, that's just the way I'm used to.

Comment: if name test does not exist?

Comment: Then this query fails, unless score_type_id is set to allow NULL. 
However, I guessed that you already had the values inserted. If not, better refer to the answer of Barmar.